# Resizing ListBoxes is done line-by-line?

Tags: .net, listbox, resize

I have a very simple form with a few anchored objects so the user can resize it. Here's what it looks like when it first opens:

[image]

(I can't seem to get Win10's crop feature to work)

Notice that the Change Directory button is lined up with the bottom of the list box. Both are anchored to the bottom, so they should move down when you make the window larger. But look at what actually happens:

[image]

Notice that the button is no longer aligned and that there is increased whitespace below the list box - the list did not resize! More specifically, the list box only resizes to sizes that are an even number of lines.

I do not like this behavior, I would like it to resize smoothly even if that means having partially visible lines. Is there a switch somewhere I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

...and it was the very next thing I tried, IntegralHeight. *sigh*